# Duda con listas

Tags: c++, lista, iteradores

tengo una duda de porque me sucede este error en el código descrito a continuación:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;



class List {
    list<int> m_list;
    list<int>::iterator it;
public:
    void loadList();
    void Element(list<int> l);
    int Element2(list<int> l, list<int>::iterator it);
};

void List::loadList() {
    m_list.push_back(3);
    m_list.push_back(4);
    m_list.push_back(5);
    m_list.push_back(7);
    m_list.push_back(9);
    Element(m_list);
}



void List::Element(list<int> l) {
    it = l.begin();
    int higher = Element2(l, it);
}
int List::Element2(list<int> l, list<int>::iterator it) {
    int higher = *(l.begin());
    if (l.begin() == it) { //Excepción no controlada en 0x0F4AE906.Se pasó un parámetro no válido
                            //a una función que produce un error irrecuperable si se especifican
                        //parámetros no válidos.
        cout << "hi";
    }
    return higher;
}


int main() {
    List l;
    l.loadList();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

No entiendo a que se debe esa excepción. ¿Alguien lo sabe?

No le hagáis caso a lo que hace realmente el programa, solo es una "representación" del código para hacer ver el error.

Comment: @eferion a mi si que me lanza excepción, a que se debe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El programa tiene un inconveniente y es que estás creando copias de las listas

```
void List::Element(list<int> l) { // l es una copia de la lista original
    it = l.begin();
    int higher = Element2(l, it);
}

int List::Element2(list<int> l, list<int>::iterator it) { // l es una copia de la 'l'  de Element()
    int higher = *(l.begin());
    if (l.begin() == it) { //Excepción no controlada en 0x0F4AE906.Se pasó un parámetro no válido
                            //a una función que produce un error irrecuperable si se especifican
                        //parámetros no válidos.
        cout << "hi";
    }
    return higher;
}
```

¿Y por qué esto es un problema? Básicamente porque lo dice el estándar de C++. Así el draft de C++0x dice lo siguiente:

> § 24.2.1
>
> An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that makes i == j. If j is reachable from i, they refer to elements of the same sequence.
>
> § 24.2.5
>
> The domain of == for forward iterators is that of iterators over the same underlying sequence.

Resumiendo y en castellano:

- El primer punto dice que dos iteradores pertenecen a la misma secuencia si existe una secuencia de incrementos que permita llegar desde un iterador al otro.
- El segundo punto dice que la comparación de iteradores es segura únicamente si ambos pertenecen a la misma secuencia.

Es decir, dos iteradores de dos listas diferentes no deben compararse entre sí porque pertenecen a secuencias distintas.

El estándar no especifica que la comparación no se deba realizar, únicamente especifica cual es el ámbito de aplicación del operador de comparación. Esto quiere decir que utilizar el operador fuera de este ámbito puede funcionar como esperas... o no.

¿La solución? Usa referencias. Así no crearás copias de las listas y los iteradores pertenecerán a la misma secuencia

```
void List::Element(list<int> & l) {
//                           ~ Referencia

int List::Element2(list<int> & l, list<int>::iterator it) {
//                           ~ Referencia
```

Ahora bien, si la lista no va a sufrir cambios sería conveniente que la referencia sea constante:

```
void List::Element(list<int> const& l) {
//                           ~~~~~~ Referencia constante

int List::Element2(list<int> const& l, list<int>::iterator it) {
//                           ~~~~~~ Referencia constante
```